# Tag merge [tag:molding] to [tag:trim]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[molding](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molding) should be a synonym of  [trim](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trim), it looks like [moulding](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moulding) already is.

Answer (score 2):

I asked about this situation in chat a while back.  If you don't have the reputation in the tag to suggest an otherwise obvious synonym, flag it and suggest the synonym in the custom message:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1823224#1823224

With apologies to the moderators for the extra work! :)

Answer (score 1):

This makes sense to me. Synonym created. Thanks Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not adverse to the idea in general, but I'm not sure trim is the obvious tag.

Comment: That's why synonyms help, you get redirected when you use a different term.